# Get user's input from many html tables and store them in a xlsx file (without having to download the file) with flask and panda

Tags: python, flask

i need to get the user's input from many html tables and store them in xlsx file, each table has to be in a different sheet, right now all i get is an empty file.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

testml = (r'C:\Users\Desktop\project2\test_input.html')
dfhtml = pd.read_html(testml)

with ExcelWriter('test_input_templates.xlsx') as writer:
dfhtml[0].to_excel(writer,'table1')
dfhtml[1].to_excel(writer,'table2')
dfhtml[2].to_excel(writer,'table3')
dfhtml[3].to_excel(writer,'table4')
dfhtml[4].to_excel(writer,'table5')
writer.save()
```

Comment: link or contents of the test html pls ?

Comment: my file is too long to be shared but it is simple, just tables inside multiple div

Comment: okay,  can you verify that the dataframes contain data ?   (ie. rows != 0).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it is just an issue with the indentation.

i create this and it works as expected creating / editing an excel and then writing the dataframes to two different sheets:

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'1':[5,6,7], '2':[1,2,3], '3':[9,8,7]}
e = {'1':[1,1,1], '2':[2,2,2], '3':[3,3,3]}

# make two different test dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
dfe = pd.DataFrame(e)

# send to excel
excel_path = "C:\\test\\test.xlsx"

with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path) as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    dfe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')

print('done')
```

result:

[image]

Also, the `writer.save()` is not necessary as the exit of the `with` block is sufficient when writing.

Comment: first i need to pass the data from javascript to flask, then convert it to a dictionary then a dataframe. Each table has to be in a different dictionary to be in a diffrent dataframe, but the problem is once i pass a js object to flask the data is too altered.